# Reuse a solution for a new task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions

I am new to C# and Sharepoint Web Services. I wrote a program awhile back, and I want to use that program as my starting point for the next project. It has all the references and resources already in place. Essentially, I want to copy the solution, and rename it, then change it to meet my current needs.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- open Windows Explorer, copy your solution and its folders, paste into a new location.
- rename your copied .sln to something else (hit key F2 from Windows Explorer)
- open that copied solution, and rename the solution (and perhaps your projects within)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the old project in visual studio and then go to File --> [Export Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185318%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and follow the wizard.

This will allow you to create a project template that will then be available with all your other project templates in File --> New project.

You can do this per project (or per item which will not help in your case). It then automatically renames your namespaces etc. if the template is configured correctly.

Comment: This might be useful if I'm doing alot of these. I might be. I'll try it, too.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward approach would probably be to just create a new solution, then manually copy all the projects under that solution and add to the new solution (right click on the solution name in Solution Explorer -> Add -> Existing Project.

From there, rename the projects if required, being careful to keep things like the Default namespace and Assembly name consistent with your new project name (you can find these under each project's properties page). Also keep an eye out for any paths that might need changed in the pre / post build steps. You will probably also want to rename the existing namespaces (right-click the namespace in code, Refactor -> Rename...)

Also, this might be a good opportunity to spot which projects will be common to both the old application and your new one, and possibly moving these to a third location from which both solutions can reference them.

Comment: Well, this is roughly what I've done so far. My project is pretty simple, one main class and one additional class in its own file (logger....) The issue really is that I had to go back and find all the references to get it back up and (sort of) running. Since they're not all named the same as they appear in the references folder, it was a pain.